# Getting __hidden at Crashlytics error reports with Enterprise Distribution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

As described in the header I keep getting __hidden in my crash reports at Crashlytics. I am distributing the app over the air via my enterprise certificate.
I looked through numerous posts here at stack overflow but no one solved my problem.
My Debug Information Format is DWARF with dSYM
The call of the Crashlytics Configuration in the app delegate is the last one as suggested on the website.
I uploaded all dSYM Files to Crashlytics.
When I export my App the Option Rebuild from Bitcode is checked (even unchecked it doesn't change). Strip Swift Symbols is unchecked.

Still I only get __hidden in the Crash Reports.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get rid of *__hidden* symbolication for distributing using enterprise certificate you should **disable** the option "***Rebuild from Bitcode***" while exporting IPA file. Also you should set "***Enable Bitcode***" for your build target in "***Build Settings***" section to ***No***.

Comment: so what do we do when disabling bitcode is not an option?

Comment: I don't have any solution for that case. But as far as I know, you are leveraging from Bitcode enabled only if the App is distributed via App Store. So you can allow Bitcode for App Store release builds and disable for other builds.